# Sending http request in node.js

Tags: http, node.js, request

I am trying to send a http request to a neo4j database using node.js. This is the code I am using:

```
var options = {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 7474,
        path: '/db/data',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            accept: 'application/json'
        }
    };

console.log("Start");
var x = http.request(options,function(res){
    console.log("Connected");
    res.on('data',function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

I check out that the database is running (I connect to the administration web page and everything is working). I am afraid that the problem is not on the database side but on the node.js side.

I hope some could give some light about this issue. I want to learn how to send a http request in node.js, the answer does not have to be specific to the neo4j issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [For someone looking for HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121590/steps-to-send-a-https-request-to-a-rest-service-in-node-js),  
[HTTPS using default Node HTTPS Module](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13127859/452708)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If it's a simple GET request, you should use `http.get()`

Otherwise, `http.request()` needs to be closed.

```
var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 7474,
    path: '/db/data',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        accept: 'application/json'
    }
};

console.log("Start");
var x = http.request(options,function(res){
    console.log("Connected");
    res.on('data',function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});

x.end();
```

Comment: When I use JSON Parse on the data it gives me the following error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: My JSON is valid perfectly working for request package.

Comment: what would be port here if I am making request to third party api