# Steps to send a https request to a rest service in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, post, get

What are the steps to send a https request in node js to a rest service?
I have an api exposed like [(Original link not working...)](https://133-70-97-54-43.sample.com/feedSample/Query_Status_View/Query_Status/Output1?STATUS=Joined%20school)

How to pass the request and what are the options I need to give for this API like
host, port, path and method?

Comment: Funny out of all the replies down below, yours is the only one that correctly answered his answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The builtin `http` and `https` modules are perfectly good if a bit low-level.  You'll probably want to use a module that handles the details for you and provides a nice higher-level API.

In node v18, node itself exposes a global [`fetch(url)`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#fetch) method, although as of 2023 it is still considered experimental and subject to change.  Also, perhaps surprisingly, node's builtin `fetch()` global does not use the HTTP stack provided by the traditional builtin `http`/`https` modules.
Instead, it uses a parallel, from-scratch HTTP stack rewrite called [undici](https://github.com/nodejs/undici).

The builtin `fetch()` is convenient, but given the instability and that it's still missing a few features, I'd avoid it in production use until the feature is more stable.

There are several popular modules available on npm.

- [<s>request</s>](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) used to be the very popular standard from the very early days of the node ecosystem, but it is no longer maintained, so you shouldn't use it in new work.
- [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) is a very popular and actively maintained HTTP library.
- [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) is another popular option that implements the fetch API.
- There are hundreds of other options of varying popularity and quality; you might want to compare the available options to see what will meet your particular needs.

Comment: Hi zeMirco, Josh, David. Thanks all of you. I got the solution as below. It is similar to Josh.

Comment: If we want to pass the body to another function, how we can do it? please clarify.

Comment: UPDATE: `request` [has been deprecated](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142), answer by Aniket is the best one as of May 2020

Comment: can stackoverflow remove request library answers because is misleading after 2020...

Comment: @josh3736 Per the documentation and path forward it is deprecated.
* request will stop accepting new features.
* request will stop considering breaking changes.

Comment: This method is Deprecated

Answer (score 81):

just use the core [https](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html) module with the [https.request](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) function. Example for a `POST` request (`GET` would be similar):

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  host: 'www.google.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

Comment: edited the above - question was about https (!) - we need var https = require('https');

Comment: I exactly do the same but got socket hang up error.
it seemed that TLS failed.

Comment: and either the request module throw same error and when I use SSLv3_methods got SSLv3 disabled error.
I really hecked up in sending a normal ssl/tls request with nodejs.

Comment: Can you please also mention how to send the post data

Answer (score 30):

Note if you are using `https.request` do not directly use the body from  `res.on('data',..`. This will fail if you have a large data coming in chunks. So you need to concatenate all the data and then process the response in `res.on('end'`. Example -

```
  var options = {
    hostname: "www.google.com",
    port: 443,
    path: "/upload",
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
    }
  };

  //change to http for local testing
  var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      body = body + chunk;
    });

    res.on('end',function(){
      console.log("Body :" + body);
      if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
        callback("Api call failed with response code " + res.statusCode);
      } else {
        callback(null);
      }
    });

  });

  req.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log("Error : " + e.message);
    callback(e);
  });

  // write data to request body
  req.write(post_data);
  req.end();
```

Comment: is there any way I can use https like `https.request(url, options, function (res) {})`. In my case I would fetching the url from mapping otherwise I have to break and again join the url to do the work.

Comment: @ChitrankDixit  I do not completely understand your use case but you can do that. Take a look at https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback. You can do `https.request(url[, options][, callback])`

Answer (score 6):

Using the request module solved the issue.

```
// Include the request library for Node.js   
var request = require('request');
//  Basic Authentication credentials   
var username = "vinod"; 
var password = "12345";
var authenticationHeader = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");
request(   
{
url : "https://133-70-97-54-43.sample.com/feedSample/Query_Status_View/Query_Status/Output1?STATUS=Joined%20school",
headers : { "Authorization" : authenticationHeader }  
},
 function (error, response, body) {
 console.log(body); }  );
```

Answer (score 4):

Since there isn't any example with a ´GET´ method here is one.
The catch is that the `path` in the `options` Object should be set to `'/'` in order to send the request correctly

```
const https = require('https')
const options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'plain/html',
    'Accept-Encoding': '*',
  }
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', d => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})

req.on('error', error => {
  console.error(`Error on Get Request --> ${error}`)
})

req.end()
```

Answer (score 1):

The example using 'GET' method is good but it can also be used with constant variables in TypeScript/Node.js setup. If that's the case, the functions on('error') and end() have to be defined outside of the https.request function.

```
const https = require('https')
const options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'plain/html',
    'Accept-Encoding': '*',
  }
}

const request = https.request(options, res => {
  const callback = (data: string) => {
    process.stdout.write(`response data: ${data}`);
  }
  res.on('data', callback)
})

request.on('error', error => {
  console.error(`Error on Get Request --> ${error}`)
})
request.end()
```