# how to connect to remote tomcat via tls from node-proxy server

Tags: node.js, tomcat, ssl, openssl, client-certificates

I have configured tomcat to accept ssl connection by configuring the keystore. since my tomcat server handles  application specific rest api calls. I want to setup a node-proxy server to proxy the request for https to tomcat, can anyone please educate me regarding how to achieve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121590/steps-to-send-a-https-request-to-a-rest-service-in-node-js - this answer may help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should work with node `request` module.

[Steps to send a https request to a rest service in Node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121590/steps-to-send-a-https-request-to-a-rest-service-in-node-js) - this answer may help you.

Thanks